# Access Watchkit Interface.storyboard in Controller file

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I am developing an AppleWatch app using watchOS 2. I am trying to access the Interface.storyboard file in a controller.swift file. I tried following code:

```
let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Interface", bundle: nil)
let interfaceController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InterfaceControllerPage") as! InterfaceController
```

But it gives me following error on first line - `Use of unresolved identifier 'UIStoryboard'`

So how do I access Storyboard in watchkit?

Basically I am trying to go back to initial view from the last view, so trying to follow the accepted answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726719/return-to-initial-view-controller-when-user-logs-out) link.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to access the storyboard to go back to initial view ? WatchKit OS might not give you access to the storyboard. But, you could use popToRootController on WKInterfaceController to go back to initial view controller.

Comment: Thanks @GeneratorOfOne ! I think I just needed popToRootController, no need to access storyboard anymore.